# Error when using geolocation react-native

Tags: geolocation, react-native

I'm using geolocation but i get the error: "undefined is not an object(evaluating 'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition')
According to documentation, it's not necessary import Geolocation using react native 0.60 version or above.

version:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.60.4

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";


export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    location: null
  };

  findCoordinates = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const location = JSON.stringify(position);
        this.setState({ location });
      },
      error => Alert.alert(error.message),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.findCoordinates}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Find My Coords?</Text>
          <Text>Location: {this.state.location}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i faced the same problem and i think that from 0.60 and above `navigator` it isn't supported so you have to use [Geolocation](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service)